# How do I generate a JSON like this?

Tags: php, json, libraries

Helo folks. I have JSON structure that I must follow, but I don't know how can I create this thing using PHP. i tried with two foreach and arrays, but when I start the third level (urlMiniatura, for example), I always get error because they need to have the label,(urlMiniatura) nd my array always receive pointer as index.

The JSON example:

```
    {
  "Tipo de ambiente 1" : {
    "ID ambiente 1" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    },
    "ID ambiente 2" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    },
    (...)
    "ID ambiente N" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    }
  },
  (...)
  "Tipo de ambiente N" : {
    "ID ambiente 1" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    },
    "ID ambiente 2" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    },
    (...)
    "ID ambiente N" : {
      "urlMiniatura" : "http://url-absoluta-da-imagem",
      "titulo" : "Nome do ambiente",
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
foreach ($this->conteudo['tipos_ambientes'] as $linha => $tipo_ambiente_item){
    //Seta valores do ambiente
    $array_retorno[$linha] = $tipo_ambiente_item['tipo_ambiente'];
    //Carrega ambientes
    $conteudo['ambientes'] = $this->ambiente_model->get_ambientes_api_by_codigo_tipo_and_codigo_tipo_ambiente(1, $tipo_ambiente_item['codigo_tipo_ambiente']);
    if ($conteudo['ambientes'] != null){
        foreach($conteudo['ambientes'] as $linha_interna => $ambiente){
            $array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna] = $ambiente['codigo_ambiente'];
            $array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna]['urlMiniatura'] = $ambiente['arquivo'];
        }
    }
}
$json = json_encode($allLinks);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: The error is in the line: $array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna]['urlMiniatura'] = $ambiente['arquivo'];

Comment: The downvotes aren't justified here imo - the OP has clearly stated their question, and has made a prior effort. Admittedly if there's an error it would be good to know what it is (!) but 5 downvotes is plainly unreasonable, as are requests to see what the OP has tried (@Nirav).

Comment: Cannot use string offset as an array in is the error.

Comment: @halfer Methinks you missed the question before it was elaborated on within the 5 minute grace period. It started even more awfully.

Comment: @SDC, Grant, Nirav - ah apologies, fair enough. Normally, initially terrible questions are visibly edited - the turnaround here is getting quicker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

You've stated that the error message is `Cannot use string offset as an array`.

This error occurs when you try to add an array element to a string variable.

For example:

```
$myString = "some text";
$myString['arrayKey'] = "more text";
```

This will fail on the secondly line because the variable is a string, and cannot be used as an array in this way.

**So how does this relate to your code?**

```
$array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna] = $ambiente['codigo_ambiente'];
$array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna]['urlMiniatura'] = $ambiente['arquivo'];
```

In the code above, you are doing something very similar to the example code I quoted; the main difference is that you've got a lot of array nesting, which makes it harder to see exactly what's happening, but the base issue is the same.

The problem is that `$ambiente['codigo_ambiente']` is a string value, and thus after the first line, `$array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna]` will also be a string.

Then in the second line, you try to add an array element to this string, and we get the error.

**How to fix it?**

The intention is clearly to have `$array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna]` as an array containing both `$ambiente['codigo_ambiente']` and `$ambiente['arquivo']`.

So we need to replace the code so that it creates them as an array, as follows:

```
$array_retorno[$linha][$linha_interna] = array(
    'titulo' => $ambiente['codigo_ambiente'],
    'urlMiniatura' => $ambiente['arquivo']
);
```

(I've taken the array key name `titulo` from your JSON example)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Solved my problema, thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the format of your input is. But say you have an array generated of the structure, PHP exposes [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that you can use to transform it to JSON. For example:

```
<?php
  $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

Apparently, according to your update, you use this method, but `$allLinks` isn't shown to be anything.

Comment: Yes, but this structure does not attend the structure that I have mentioned.

Comment: So put _your_ structure _in_. But it must be a something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$json = json_encode($allLinks);` this is wrong you dont have `$allLinks` assigned

i guess it should be  `$json = json_encode($array_retorno);`